# Copying Conditional formatting in Excel using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column 'A' in worksheet 'two' and another column 'B' in worksheet 'one' !

I want to copy the conditional formatting of Column A in two to Column B in one !

Basically, I want to copy everything from Column A in two to Column B in one except the data !

Please help !!

I have :

```
sheetA & sheetB object as Objects in my code
I am using VB.NET
```

I am a newbie in Vb.net - Please Help !

Comment: What have you tried on this so far.  It will be easier to help you if you make an attempt and post what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of a push:

```
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Book = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Test2.xlsx")
    Sheet = Book.Worksheets(1)
    SourceRange = Sheet.Range("A1:A" & Sheet.Range("A1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row)
    DestRange = Sheet.Range("D1:D" & Sheet.Range("D1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row)
```

> The meat of it is this part, where you take the format conditions from one range and add it to the other.  This assumes there is only one criterion for formatting.  More than one would require that you would step over all of them (I think there are up to 3) by using **SourceRange.FormatConditions(i)** in a loop from 1 to **SourceRange.FormatConditions.Count**

```
    DestRange.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Operator, SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Formula1)
    DestRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = SourceRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Comment: @Yugal Glad it did.  I learned a lot in formulating the answer!